# My visual studio code extension not running

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating my first extension in VSCode and it gives me this error when I try to run it[image: The error]

I've got node.js and git but still getting this error please help

I searched the internet for help but I didn't get anything

Comment: what is the problem to post the text of the error message, searching in images for a similar error is impossible

Comment: you don't execute an extension with `npm run`

Comment: Did you ever install NPM on this Windows machine? If you did, have you restarted VS Code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I cannot understand why you want to run "npm run watch" in "C:\Windows\System32**"

If you want to run any command then can you not get the current folder dir and run on it?

Maybe this error is because of a security issue.

Comment: I doubt this is a thing that anyone "want" but how the default extension skeleton generated by yocode works.

Comment: That is just the location of PowerShell on his machine. I don't imagine he is watching that folder.